# Detecting Facebook API version at runtime?

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

What's a quick way to detect Facebook API version at runtime?

I'm not trying to do anything fancy with it, just to understand if the page I'm looking at happens to be using an ancient FB version somehow (debugging something related to FB init process). The specific API I'm referring to is the Like button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Facebook API isn't versioned - it's updated daily and with the biggest changes happening once a week.

There are also occasional updates to the supported SDKs, but they all call the same API, and unless the problem you're encountering is specific to the SDK itself, using a specific SDK shouldn't affect your app.

If it's the Javascript SDK - the SDK is loaded directly (at `connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js` ) from Facebook, and is updated from Facebook's side daily

Comment: So it doesn't contain a build number? Some sites might try to "be smart" and copy the facebook javascripts themselves locally (granted, this is just a hypothesis here... I've seen sites do crazy stuff with other 3rd party libs, not Facebook specifically)

Comment: There's a build timestamp/number at the top of the all.js file if that's useful for detecting changes, but there's no official versioning